# Get class attribute of the selected item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In the following HTML, when I click on any list item, I want to add a class `.active` to it.
After that when I click on the link, I want to get the class of the li (excluding .active).

For example, by clicking on first li, it should add `.active` class to it, and by clicking the link, it should get the class `one`.

I can add the class to it, but cannot get the attached class value by clicking on the link.

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li class="one">One</li>
    <li class="two">Two</li>
    <li class="three">Three</li>    
</ul>

<a href="#" class="select">Check Selected </a>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).on('click','ul li',function(e){
        $('ul li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });

$(document).on('click','.select',function(e){
       var abc = $('ul li.active').attr('class');
         alert('Selected li class is ' + abc);    
    });
```

**Demo:**
http://jsfiddle.net/n9awc/

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.select', function (e) {
    var abc = $('ul li.active').attr('class').replace('active', '');
    alert('Selected li class is ' + abc);
});
```

Demo : [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/n9awc/3/)

---

`$('ul li.active').attr('class')` will return a string having all the classes like `one active` or `two active`. We can now simply remove this `active` string from it using [`String.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Answer (score 2):

Use `.split()`

```
alert($('ul li.active').attr('class').split(' ')[0]);
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jjba6/)

Here, am splitting the string with space, and than am returning 1st index value using `[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
    <ul>
        <li class="one">One</li>
        <li class="two">Two</li>
        <li class="three">Three</li>    
    </ul>

    <a href="#" class="select">Check Selected </a>

    $('ul').on('click','li',function(){
// in case of if some li element has the active class, left quit
$('li .active').removeClass('active')
        $(this).addClass("active');
    })


    $('.select').click(function(){
  alert("You've click" + $('.active').text())
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you save the class to a variable?

```
$(document).on('click','ul li',function(e){
    var thisClass = $(this).attr('class');

    $('ul li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

Comment: But what happen when we click on the li more than once?